# Add a Dynamically added field inside a dynamically added field in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xazxyK

This is my link. Now the problem is I need to add description[] multiple times  which is inside row[] which I am already adding multiple times. So, How can I able to implement the same.

```
data: {
    rows: [{
        title: '',
        description: [{
            name: '',
            age: '',
        }]
    }]
},
```

So, How can I able to add description dynamically inside rows[] ? Please do a help

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? You're using `v-model` which already adds your description dynamically inside your `rows`array ?

Comment: sir, i need to add description dynamically, but not name inside the row

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're trying to do. Could you provide an example ?

Comment: Sir, I my codepen, I am able to add name,description dynamically. Actually my first part is correct. So, please check the rows[] here and in the example. Here description is again an array, and I need to add it also multiple times. my json data should become row[{title: 'abcd', description:[{name:'sdf',age:''20},{name:'ssdf',age:''22}]}]. Now it is row[{title:'abcd',description:'asdvf'}]

Comment: @ThomasLombart Hope you get what I am looking for

Comment: are you want more object on description array ? like more {name: '', age:''} ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely @EmtiazZahid

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for but you would need to change your `addRow` method to make your description return an object and not an empty string.

Comment: I need to dynamically add description fields (name and age). So for I title, I can have many description(name and age)

Answer (score 0):

There was some problem in your array push.

your data should be like this:

```
data: {
       rows: {
           title:  '',
           description: [{
               name: '',
               age: '',
           }]
       }
  },
```

Please have a look on this codepan: https://codepen.io/emtiazzahid/pen/MqXwPv
Its work fine

Comment: but name and age is not updating.

Comment: yes, from where you want to get the data in name and age ?

Comment: But how can I add rows as well as description

Comment: code updated, please have a look. this.rows.push({
                        title:  "",
                        description: [{
                          name: '',
                          age: '',
                          }]
                    });